# Gravação de arquivos em Java

Tags: java

Eu preciso gravar nomes e notas de alunos, segue o código (o `switch` é para implementação de outras funções no futuro).

Eu insiro a turma (com o diretório e nome do arquivo de texto), nome do aluno e suas notas e guardo elas na matriz e no vetor, porém na hora de escreve-las no arquivo, apenas a primeira linha que foi digitada está lá. Por exemplo: João [4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,media].

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String nomes[] = new String[100];
    double notas[][] = new double[100][5];
    String resposta = "S";
    double media = 0;
    double soma = 0;
    String turma = "";
    String resposta1 = "s";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("O que deseja fazer? LANCAR notas, ver NOTAS, ver RESULTADOS, SAIR?");
    String opcao = input.nextLine();
    while (resposta.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
        switch (opcao) {
            case "lancar":
                while (resposta1.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= nomes.length; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Qual o nome da turma?");
                        turma = input.nextLine();
                        input = new Scanner(System.in);
                        System.out.println("Qual o nome do aluno?");
                        nomes[i] = input.nextLine();
                        for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
                            System.out.println("Qual a nota " + j);
                            notas[i][j] = input.nextDouble();
                            soma = soma + notas[i][j];
                            media = soma / 4;
                            notas[i][4] = media;
                        }
                        System.out.println("Deseja lançar notas de outro aluno? S/N?");
                        resposta1 = input.next();
                        media = 0;
                        soma = 0;
                        if (resposta1.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        File medias = new File(turma);
                        FileWriter gravador = new FileWriter(medias, true);
                        for (int p = 0; p <= nomes.length; p++) {
                            for (int q = 0; q < 4; q++) {
                                if (notas[p][q] > 0.0) {
                                    gravador.write(nomes[p]);
                                    gravador.write(Arrays.toString(notas[p]));
                                    System.out.printf(String.format("Arquivo %s gravado com sucesso!", turma));
                                    gravador.flush();
                                    gravador.close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.printf("Erro na gravação do arquivo: %s.\n", e.getMessage());
                    }

                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu recomendaria você ultilizar o [OutputStrean](http://www.devmedia.com.br/classe-inputstream-e-outputstream-em-java/32007) Acho que seu problema seria resolvido mais facil.

Answer (score 0):

Está imprimindo apenas o primeiro elemento porque você fecha seu FileWriter após a primeira entrada no if, nessa parte aqui:

```
FileWriter gravador = new FileWriter(medias, true);
for (int p = 0; p <= nomes.length; p++) {
    for (int q = 0; q < 4; q++) {
        if (notas[p][q] > 0.0) {
            gravador.write(nomes[p]);
            gravador.write(Arrays.toString(notas[p]));
            System.out.printf(String.format("Arquivo %s gravado com sucesso!", turma));
            gravador.flush();
            gravador.close(); // Erro nesta parte
        }
    }
}
```

Você deve fechar seu FileWriter após escrever tudo que deseja, ou seja fora dos dois laços **for**.